# Sentence that have a different word usage?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

I was recently reading an article where the word "by" was used in a sentence to describe a season (football season)

> Sentence: The competition is getting tougher by the season.

Now, as per my understanding the word "by" and if used following an article, the article justifies an object.

> For example:- He was standing by the tree.

How would you describe the usage of by in the sentence?

Comment: There are several different ways to use *by*. Have you tried looking in references, dictionaries or learners guides, to see if you can understand the different usages?

Comment: Yes, I went through that process before questioning here but was not satisfied with any references. Most of them were used in context to time, object or person.

Answer (score 2):

*by the (period of time)* is an expression that is used to describe something that increases or otherwise changes over said period of time. Ex. *by the day*, *by the minute*, etc. Here, the competition gets more tough each season. Season 1 would be less tough than season 2, which would be less tough than season 3, etc.

Prepositions in English often have many different uses and can have specific meanings that are different from the standalone meanings when they’re part of an idiomatic expression like this.

Comment: can also be used 'season by season' to indicate each one indicates a progressive level. (eg a computer game gets harder level by level - each level is harder than the previous)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Where can I get the details about such prepositions which are different from their standalone meanings?

Comment: @Rajat Audichya, idioms can often be found in the dictionary as well as individual words. Also, I may have spoken too quickly saying that the meaning of *by* is *different* in this expression- it is different from the meaning “next to”, which is maybe the most common and the one you know. See [definitions 6b - ex. “by the lb” and 10 - what Smock is talking about](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by) here. Prepositions in English do often have a lot of different meanings each, and it might help to know some common expressions like “by the X”.